# Deploy Docker Image to CF using Travis CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push my docker image to CF landscape through Travis build.

I have a Dockerfile. I created a image pushed it to docker hub. Now I have to push this image from docker hub to CF using Travis CI. 
To push an app normally to CF using Travis - We use this :

```
deploy:
   provider: cloudfoundry
   username: hulk_hogan@example.com
   password: supersecretpassword
   api: https://api.run.pivotal.io
   organization: myawesomeorganization
   space: staging
   manifest: manifest-staging.yml       # (optional)  Defaults to manifest.yml.
   app_name: My app name                # (optional)
```

But not sure how this works wrt docker image.

Comment: If they don't provide that option, you could always run a script & have it call `cf push -o <image> <app-name>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it how to achieve.
We can use docker attribute in manifest.yml
See [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#docker)

And travis.yml shall look like as it is mentioned above.